# How to set negative translationX before app load

Tags: java, android, translation, runnable

when I set a view's translationX whether via XML or programmatically android seems to ignore the code.

When I run view.setTranslationX(-200); it ignores the translation and the app shows the view at 200 instead

If I run via post Runnable or overriding onMeasure it can be moved to -200 but it momentarily shows when the app loads. I don't want it to be seen on app start

What can I do to translate view before widget is shown.

When is the earliest I can set translationX?

Answer (score 0):

The view/layout is not inflated yet so you can't.

Do you mind if I ask why you want to do it before the widget is shown?

Comment: I want the view to be of screen when I first load the app.. when I hide the view after the app start there is a nasty lag

Comment: @BretJoseph  if you don't want the view to be visible at first just set its visibility to INVISIBLE or GONE (in your xml file), it won't show up until you make it visible.